# Conditional count over rows over multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to answer this question: How many patients have had more than 1 scan?   Pseudocode:

```
Countif >1 (Ans = 2. Two patients have 2 or more scans)
    For each Patient ID, count if "scan" nonblank (Ans: a=1, b=2, c=2, d=1)

      A          | B      | C
 01   Patient ID | Scan   | Other data etc
 02   a          |        | 
 03   a          | 1/1/15 |
 04   b          | 2/2/15 |
 05   b          |        |
 06   b          | 3/2/16 | 
 07   c          | 1/3/14 |
 08   d          | 2/1/12 |
 09   c          | 1/7/14 |
 10   d          |        |
```

This is easy to do for just one patient. I.e., `=Countifs(A1:10,"a",B1:10,"<>")`. How do you count this for all patients?

Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You will require a helper column - refer the formula below

Helper column `=IF(AND(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$10,A2)>1,NOT(ISBLANK(B2)) ),A2,"-")`

```
=IF(COUNTIF(C2:C10,"-")>0,SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(C2:C10,C2:C10))-1,SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(C2:C10,C2:C10)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input. Though, I should have clarified something. Some patients don't have scans on certain days. I.e. they are blank purposefully.

Comment: Updated the helper formula check answer - This will not count the patients that do not have scan dates

Answer (score 1):

The formula will need to be entered as an array (once copy and pasted while still in the formula bar hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>)

`=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(B2:B10<>"",MATCH(A2:A10,A2:A10,0)),ROW(A2:A10)-ROW(A2)+1)>1))`

Comment: Thanks! This is the best solution I believe :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a sheet with every patient you can add a column and use your formula `=Countifs(A1:10,"patient_id",B1:10,"<>")` to count the number of scans for each patient and then use the same type of formula to count every sum of scans that are greater than 1.

#### Patient sheet

```
      A          | B     
 01   Patient ID | Scans  
 02   a          | =COUNTIFS(scans!A2:A10; A2;scans!B2:B10;"<>")     
 03   b          | 2      
 04   c          | 2      
 05   d          | 1      
 06   e          | 0  
 07   f          | 0
```

#### Scan sheet

```
      A          | B      | C
 01   Patient ID | Scan   | Other data etc
 02   a          |        | 
 03   a          | 1/1/15 |
 04   b          | 2/2/15 |
 05   b          |        |
 06   b          | 3/2/16 | 
 07   c          | 1/3/14 |
 08   d          | 2/1/12 |
 09   c          | 1/7/14 |
 10   d          |        |
```

#### Where you want

```
=COUNTIF(patients!B2:B6;">1")
```